# Working in android studio. My mobile apears offline while I try to run the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I keep getting this bug where my mobile appears offline when I try to run/debug my app in Android Studio.

I have searched the internet for some help. I tried the following things:

Remove cable -> reinsert the cable.
Remove cable -> Remove app from mobile -> reinsert the cable.
Restart pc.
Restart mobile.
Exit ADB.
uncheck USB debugging -> recheck USB debugging.
Revoke USB debugging authorization.
Try other USB port.

Sometimes one of this steps works. Most of the time nothing happens, and I lose so much time to this issue.

Does anyone know why my phone goes offline? And does someone know a permanent fix for this issue? its really annoying.

Comment: maybe pairing usb devices helps(it exists in some mobiles not all).

Comment: Does the Window show your device at all, sometimes the connection is loose, so that shows offline. Get a proper cable

Comment: It was the cable. Thank you so much @NirajSanghani :)

Comment: Happy to help. Sometimes it's just the stupidest things that frigging just kill us